# Downloading an Azure Storage Blob using pure JavaScript and Azure-Storage-Js

Tags: javascript, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, filesaver.js

I'm trying to do this with just pure Javascript and the SDK.  I am **not** using Node.js.  I'm converting my application from v2 to v10 of the SDK [azure-storage-js-v10](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-js/tree/master/blob#azure-storage-sdk-v10-for-javascript---blob)

> The azure-storage.blob.js bundled file is compatible with UMD
>   standard,  if no module system is found, following global variable
>   will be exported: **azblob**

My code is here:

```
const serviceURL = new azblob.ServiceURL(`https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net${accountSas}`, pipeline);
const containerName = "container";
const containerURL = azblob.ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(serviceURL, containerName);
const blobURL = azblob.BlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, blobName);

const downloadBlobResponse = await blobURL.download(azblob.Aborter.none, 0);
```

The downloadBlobResponse looks like this:
[downloadBlobResponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAxH3.png)

Using v10, how can I convert the downloadBlobResponse into a new blob so it can be used in the [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) saveAs() function?

In [azure-storage-js-v2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node#azure-storage-javascript-client-library-for-browsers) this code worked on smaller files:

```
let readStream = blobService.createReadStream(containerName, blobName, (err, res) => {
    if (error) {
        // Handle read blob error
    }
});

// Use event listener to receive data
readStream.on('data', data => {
    // Uint8Array retrieved
    // Convert the array back into a blob
    var newBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)]);
    // Saves file to the user's downloads directory
    saveAs(newBlob, blobName); // FileSaver.js
});
```

I've tried everything to get v10 working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the body by await blobBody.

```
downloadBlobResponse = await blobURL.download(azblob.Aborter.none, 0);

// data is a browser Blob type
const data = await downloadBlobResponse.blobBody;
```

Comment: I up-voted your answer, but, I get this stupid response...  "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 1):

Thanx Mike Coop and Xiaoning Liu!

I was busy making a Vuejs plugin to download blobs from a storage account. Thanx to you, I was able to make this work.

```
var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
const downloadButton = document.getElementById("download-button");

const downloadFiles = async() => {
    try {
        if (fileList.selectedOptions.length > 0) {
            reportStatus("Downloading files...");
            for await (const option of fileList.selectedOptions) {
                var blobName = option.text;
                const account = '<account name>';
                const sas = '<blob sas token>';
                const containerName = '< container name>';
                const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net${sas}`);
                const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
                const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
                const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download(blobName, 0, undefined);
                const data = await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody;
                // Saves file to the user's downloads directory
                FileSaver.saveAs(data, blobName); // FileSaver.js
            }
            reportStatus("Done.");
            listFiles();
        } else {
            reportStatus("No files selected.");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        reportStatus(error.message);
    }
};

downloadButton.addEventListener("click", downloadFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Xiaoning Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4246409/xiaoning-liu-msft)!

I'm still learning about async javascript functions and promises.  Guess I was just missing another "**await**".  I saw that "downloadBlobResponse.blobBody" was a promise and also a blob type, but, I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't convert to a new blob.  I kept getting the "**Iterator getter is not callable**" error.

Here's my final working solution:

```
// Create a BlobURL
const blobURL = azblob.BlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, blobName);

// Download blob
downloadBlobResponse = await blobURL.download(azblob.Aborter.none, 0);

// In browsers, get downloaded data by accessing downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody
const data = await downloadBlobResponse.blobBody;

// Saves file to the user's downloads directory
saveAs(data, blobName); // FileSaver.js
```

Comment: where does error "Iterator getter is not callable" come from?

Comment: I was getting that error when trying to convert the **blobURL.download** response into a new blob object. `var newBlob = new Blob(downloadBlobResponse.blobBody);`  After adding the **await** keyword I realized that creating a new blob wasn't even necessary.  Thanks again!