# How to retrieve and display (in browser) urls for multiple pdf's stored in an azure storage account using JavaScript v12 SDK for Browsers

Tags: javascript, sdk, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm new to azure and trying to loop through a storage account > container to get the URL/URI for each of the pdf documents that are stored. I then want the URL to be used as the value for the href tag, so when users click the link, it displays the PDF in the browser or downloads it. I know how to create an a href, but I don't know how to retrieve the URL to the pdfs.

I started using the [Quickstart: Manage blobs with JavaScript v12 SDK in a browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser), and that helped a bit, but I wasn't able to determine what I need to do to get a link to each PDF to display in the web site.

At this point my JavaScript code is simple and pretty much follows the quickstart. The code (listFiles function) currently correctly displays the file name as it is supposed to, but I have no idea how to get the href value for it. I've been trying to find information in the [SDK docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest), but haven't been successful. There is another stackoverflow article that kind of talks about it, but doesn't provide enough details. Here is my JavaScript code:

index.js

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
const main = document.getElementById("main");

// Update <placeholder> with your Blob service SAS URL string
const blobSasUrl = "<myblobservicesasurlstring>";

// Create a new BlobServiceClient
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobSasUrl);

// Create a unique name for the container by 
// pdfs container already exists in blob storage
const containerName2 = "pdfs";

// Get a container client from the BlobServiceClient
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName2);

const listFiles = async () => {
    main.innerHTML = "";
    try {
        let iter = containerClient.listBlobsFlat();
        let blobItem = await iter.next();
        while (!blobItem.done) {
            main.innerHTML += `<a href='${blobItem.uri}'>${blobItem.value.name}</a>`;
            blobItem = await iter.next();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
};

window.addEventListener("load", listFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. You have a SAS link which I assume is for the storage account or container as you are able to list your blobs from it. Your account looks like this `https://{storageaccountname}.blob.core.windows.net/?{keyinfo}`. The one for a specific file would be the same but with the container and file name in the path. `https://{storageaccountname}.blob.core.windows.net/{containername}/{filename}?{keyinfo}`
2. Instead of an href attribute, instead have a link that uses your blobClient to generate the download inside JS. It is a bit cleaner, but it will have the same end result so it is up to your preference. You can see a sample that includes doing this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/b4582fe142fa598011d72e7b0b24fc39494113eb/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript/basic.js#L73).

Code Summary (also borrowing a bit from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151220/downloading-an-azure-storage-blob-using-pure-javascript-and-azure-storage-js) answer):

```
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
const data = await downloadBlobResponse.blobBody;

// Saves file to the user's downloads directory
saveAs(data, blobName); // FileSaver.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve the problem, it might not be the most direct way, but it works:

```
const { BlobServiceClient, BlobClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const main = document.getElementById("main");

// Update <placeholder> with your Blob service SAS URL string
const blobSasUrl = "<MyBlobServiceSASURL>";

// Create a new BlobServiceClient
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobSasUrl);
const _connectionString = "<myconnectionstring>";
const _containerName = "pdfs";

// Get a container client from the BlobServiceClient
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(_containerName);

const listFiles = async () => {
    
    main.innerHTML = "";
    try {
        
        let iter = containerClient.listBlobsFlat();
        
        let blobItem = await iter.next();
        
        while (!blobItem.done) {
            
            let _blobName2 = blobItem.value.name;
            let blobClient = new BlobClient(_connectionString, _containerName, _blobName2);
            
            main.innerHTML += `<div><a href='${blobClient.url}'>${blobItem.value.name}</a></div>`;
            blobItem = await iter.next();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
};


window.addEventListener("load", listFiles);
```